# C# vs. Java: generics covariance and contravariance

Tags: c#, java, generics, covariance, contravariance

Both `C#` and `java` implement generics *covariance* and *contravariance*, but in a quite different manner: C# restricts co- and contra-variance to generics interfaces, Java enables it to any generics class or method.

- What are exactly the differences regarding to the syntax?
- What kind of code is possible in one language that is not possible in the other language?
- What are the practical limitations due to the lack of integration in their respective framework (i.e. missing implementation of default collection)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Now this sure screams homework...

Comment: @PAH disagree, the question is interesting; no related question shown on the right really answers that

Comment: ... If I were a Computer Science Professor, I would indeed ask this question to my students... :-)

Comment: Java doesn't even have declaration-site variance, so you could say it restricts it *more* and not less than C#. Use-site type bounds are not at all the same as variance, they just cover some of the same needs.

Comment: Thank you for the precision. Is there an umbrella term for *declaration-site variance* and *use-site type bounds*? So that I can fix the terminology in the question... Anyway, the question is rather a practical one, focusing on how to use and why to avoid using both features for `C#` and `java` developers ...